# How to fix 403 Error in production server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I have problem with   :     `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();`     and     `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`
each time I click on **back** on the browser or I **refresh**  the page with `location.reload();` I get 403 error (Forbidden), this problem i have it only in the production server, in my local it's working fine, can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Do you have SSL enabled?

Comment: @mostafa8026 Yes

Comment: maybe this link be useful for you: https://forums.asp.net/t/1957446.aspx?ValidationAntiForgeryToken+not+working+correctly+when+I+enable+SSL+to+cookies+in+ASP+NET+MVC